# Rails, should I optimize my view or my queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, activerecord, view

If my Rails development console shows 'view completed in' a time that is much greater than the 'active record completed in' time frame, should I optimize my views, or queries?

`Completed 200 OK in 8441ms (Views: 7277.3ms | ActiveRecord: 316.9ms)`

Granted, both are horrendous but, the views take much longer to render... Is there a way I should consider re-writing the views vs. changing the way the queries are performed?

Comment: We can't really help without more information on what's taking so long to render, perhaps post a portion of your view / controller?  Also, have you tried selectively removing sections of your view to determine which part is the largest contributor to the rendering time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you need to optimize your views.  Even if you shaved half the time off your database queries, the page would still take over seven seconds to render!

Attack the problem with the biggest payoff.  In this case, cutting your view time in half takes your page from seven seconds down to three seconds.  That's a pretty big win.

As MBHNYC mentioned, you should also determine whether the time is spent in the views or in the controllers setting up the information for your views.